Splunk Dashboard Studio - Send substr as token?
I'm trying to pass a token from one dashboard in Dashboard Studio to another drill-down dashboard.

This passes the value I need to the drill-down:

Is there a way to pass the token as SUBSTR instead so I get this result:

I have tried
row.substr(HP,1,2).value

But that did not work.
